# Winpcap with jnetpcap and Windows 10

Tags: java, pcap, winpcap, jnetpcap, pcap4j

According to [WinPcap website](https://www.winpcap.org/install/default.htm), they don't support Windows 10 but latest release of famous network analyzer, Wireshark (2.6.6) which can run on Windows 10 still uses WinPcap in its installation. On the other hand, they warn you about WinPcap usage on Windows 10 in [their wiki](https://wiki.wireshark.org/WinPcap) by saying that "The Wireshark installer includes WinPcap, but Npcap might work better for you especially if you run Windows 10." My question is, how much reliable to use Winpcap on Windows 10? If it is not reliable, can I still use jnetPcap with newer alternative of Winpcap (such as Npcap). Since I already have an old Java implementation using jnetpcap developed on Windows 7 and I will maintain it again, I want to keep it as much as possible.

Comment: The latest WinPcap release is from 2013, Windows 10 was introduced 2015 - therefore you won't find anything regarding Win10 compatibility in the changelog. jnetPcap is just a Java wrapper/JAva API for WinPCap. YOu can#T run it without WinPcap.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Win10Pcap](http://www.win10pcap.org/) instead, which is built for Windows 10 and is binary compatible with WinPcap.

Comment: on your github webpage, you say that we can use winpcap 4.1.2 (which doesn't support Windows 10) with pcap4j on Windows 10. What I understand that I can use pcap4j wiith winpcap 4.1.2 on Windows 10 but I can have some problems. My question is what kind of problems can occur with this configuration on Windows 10?

Comment: I've never seen any problems with WinPcap 4.1.2 on Windows 10, but I can't say won't occur.
I thinnk you'd better use Win10Pcap or Npcap on Windows 10.

Comment: Note that Winpcap may also stop working at anytime, when Microsoft decides that all very old driver certificates need to be updated. Moreover, it still uses NDIS 5 (which is deprecated, and will probably be dropped in a future W10 update)